# Trying to call a hasChildNodes method but getting cannot read property of Null

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm attempting to make a simple turn-based two player game (like FE) as practice for an upcoming project. In trying to ensure that no characters overlap on the same grid tile, I tried to make a validator function that I can call for each character on generation (randomly generated locations), so that I wouldn't have the same script with minor changes in each character gen section. My original code (without the function) is above, the most recent attempt (with some context) is below:

```
    function bTeamCharGen() {
      var a = 10;
      var b = 15;
      var c = 0;
      var d = 5;

      var bTeamLead = document.createElement("img");
      bTeamLead.src = "images/transp_img.gif";
      bTeamLead.height = "38";
      bTeamLead.width = "38";
      bTeamLead.className = "lead";
      bTeamLead.id = "bLead";
      genStartPos();
      var curr = document.getElementById("gridBlock_" + i + "_" + j);
      if (curr.hasChildNodes()) {
        while (curr.hasChildNodes()) {
          genStartPos(a, b, c, d);
        }
      }
      document.getElementById("gridBlock_" + i + "_" + j).appendChild(bTeamLead);
      document.getElementById("bLead").style.background = "url('images/eirika_1_1.gif') 0 0";
      document.getElementById("bLead").style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
      //commented out basic structure for further characters here
    }
```

This is the original code for one of the characters. The following is what I've currently arrived at (and still with the Uncaught TypeError):

```
    var i, j;

    //functions to generate grid and background

    function genStartPos(minX, maxX, minY, maxY) {
      i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxX - minX + 1) + minX);
      j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxY - minY + 1) + minY);
    }

    function validStartPos() {
      genStartPos();
      var curr = document.getElementById("gridBlock_" + i + "_" + j);
      if (curr.hasChildNodes()) {
        while (curr.hasChildNodes()) {
          genStartPos(a, b, c, d);
        }
      }
    }

    function bTeamCharGen() {
      var a = 10;
      var b = 15;
      var c = 0;
      var d = 5;

      var bTeamLead = document.createElement("img");
      bTeamLead.src = "images/transp_img.gif";
      bTeamLead.height = "38";
      bTeamLead.width = "38";
      bTeamLead.className = "lead";
      bTeamLead.id = "bLead";
      validStartPos();
      document.getElementById("gridBlock_" + i + "_" + j).appendChild(bTeamLead);
      document.getElementById("bLead").style.background = "url('images/eirika_1_1.gif') 0 0";
      document.getElementById("bLead").style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";

      //commented out basic structure for further characters here
    }

    function initialise() {
      makeGrid();
      setBackground();
      bTeamCharGen();
      rTeamCharGen();
    }
```

It's a bit long and unwieldy, as I'm still trying to neaten it up quite a bit, but everything else worked until I did this. I'm calling the initialise function as an onload for the body, and the `<script>` is within the `<head>`, since I had problems earlier on when having it within `<body>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but... I think you trying get element when `"gridBlock_" + i + "_" + j` is `undefined`

You calling `genStartPos()` without any parameter. So your `i` and `j` are undefined, so you string with element id.

If you cant pass variables to `genStartPos()`, you need to make some default value for maxX, maxY...

PS you also calling `genStartPos(a, b, c, d)` when a, b, c, d are undefined. Or maybe this just not all code you show

Comment: Yeah, there's quite a bit more code, but those are independent functions from these and haven't been changed at all.
The `"gridblock _" + i "_" + "j"` is one of the first things in there (it's defined in `makeGrid()`), but everything else that's using that as it's base is working fine, so I doubt it's that.
For ` genStartPos(a, b, c, d)`, I have them defined within `bTeamCharGen()`.
So the parameters won't pass down through `validStartPos` to `genStartPos(a, b, c, d)` when called in `bTeamCharGen()`? I can see how that could be a problem otherwise, but not with the Uncaught TypeError...

Comment: @Kristen Ramcharan, your a, b, c, d in `bTeamCharGen()` are local. they define only in this function, so `validStartPos()` doesn't know about them

Comment: Ah, okay... but then assuming I define them in `validStartPos()` (or otherwise pass on the values from `bTeamCharGen()` then that shouldn't be a problem. I'll work on that as well, thank you very much!